# apps-script TextArea: can't scroll text into view with setCursorPos

Tags: scroll, textarea, google-apps-script

I have a long text in a gas TextArea and I want to scroll a line of text into view. I tried several solutions (setCursorPos, setSelectionRange), but the text is always displayed at the top; i.e. it never scrolls down to the position I want...

I did notice that the doc says: "This will only work when the TextArea is attached to the document and not hidden.". That shouldn't really apply in my case (I want the app to pop up at the specific position...), but I tried to set it before and after the app is displayed.

Here is the code.

```
....
var cursorPos=15;//just a test...
var fileString = "a very long text that I'm not putting in here....";
var mytextArea=myapp.createTextArea().setValue(fileString).setSize("100%","100%").setName("TextArea").setId("TextArea");
myapp.add(mytextArea.setCursorPos(cursorPos));
var doc=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
doc.show(myapp);
myapp.getElementById("TextArea").setFocus().setCursorPos(cursorPos);
```

I must be doing something obviously wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should open an issue in the issue tracker. As a matter of fact, there is no widget that has the focus when the UI is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the remark: I put this post in http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/ ; not sure if that is the right place!

Comment: Yes, thats the right place. Please update this thread with the issue number

Comment: Issue is here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1635

Comment: The issue response was: "Unfortunately this is a limitation of the underlying GWT technology" :( So no fix any time soon....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1635
The issue response was: "Unfortunately this is a limitation of the underlying GWT technology" :( So no fix any time soon... : i.e setCursorPos(cursorPos) does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the text area in a scroll panel and setting the position of the scroll panel?

Comment: Will give that a try (I have forgotten now which application needed that function!)